# Startup: Windows opens many instances of Edge, each with "ERROR:file_io_win.cc(180)] CreateFile settings.dat: Access is denied. (0x5)"

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, windows-10, automated-tests, microsoft-edge

A few weeks ago I'd been testing websites using Selenium WebDriver in C# (Visual Studio). I've had a lot of fun testing multiple browers.

Since about a week ago, when I turn on/start up my PC, automatically 20 or so instances of Microsoft Edge appear on screen showing the error

[XXX76:XXX68:XXX8/XXXX20.442:ERROR:file_io_win.cc(180)] CreateFile settings.dat: Access is denied. (0x5)

in a window that looks like the console but is definitely Edge.

I get that it's something to do with not being permitted to create/read this file but it's getting quite nuisant.

Why could this be happening?

*I've replaced the numbers with Xs in the error because it looks like an IP Address or something like that.*

Comment: Can you please inform us the version of the Selenium web driver, version of the Selenium, version of the Edge browser and version of the OS build? It can help us to test the issue and it can help to narrow down the issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: I suggest you refer the steps mentioned in [this link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/articles/known-issue-microsoft-edge-launching-on-startup/m-p/1457853) and try to provide the feedback to Microsoft using the Edge browser. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Can you pls
1. Leave the Edge command windows opened
2. Open Task Manager
3. Switch to the Details tab
4. Right click on the “Name” column header
5. Click “Select columns”
6. Check “Command line” to include the command line in the details list
7. Post a screenshot of the msedge.exe process(es) and their command line(s) as they appear in the Details list
feel free to blur any sensitive info there.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue, and have no reason for why. However, I managed to deal with it by opening the Task Manager (CTRL+SHIFT+ESC), going to the Startup tab, then Disabling each of the multiple Microsoft Edge instances.

Comment: I just did that and after restarting my Windows 10, the issue doesn't appear anymore. But I really wonder why on the Task Manager --> Startup tab, there are sooo many Microsoft Edge instances (in my case probably 10 or more). No idea why Microsoft is doing that.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in python - disabling Microsoft Edge instances in "Startup Apps" helped but new instances got created/turned on every time the program runs...

In python I added a driver option that seemed to fix the problem: driverOptions.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
(see https://stackoverflow.com/a/64146083/9825881)

For C# I haven't tested but the equivalent might be:

```
List<string> ls = new List<string>();
ls.Add("enable-logging");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddExcludedArguments(ls);

using (IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver("C:\\Program\\chromedriver", options)){
-----
```

Answer (score 0):

@Deepak-MSFT

I get the pretty same issue:
[image]

**OS**: Windows 10 Pro, Version=2004, OS build=19041.508

**Selenium WebDriver**: 3.141.0

**Visual Studio**: VS2019, Version16.6.2

**Edge Browser**: Version 85.0.564.51 (Official build) (64-bit)

**NugetPackage**: Microsoft.Edge.SeleniumTools version 3.141.2

Some more info: I installed new Chromium Edge manually before Windows roll it out. And now is on latest Windows Update.

Update:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for providing the environment related information. I suggest you refer the steps mentioned in [this link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/articles/known-issue-microsoft-edge-launching-on-startup/m-p/1457853) and try to provide the feedback to Microsoft using the Edge browser. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Thank you Deepak

Comment: Can you pls
1. Leave the Edge command windows opened
2. Open Task Manager
3. Switch to the Details tab
4. Right click on the “Name” column header
5. Click “Select columns”
6. Check “Command line” to include the command line in the details list
7. Post a screenshot of the msedge.exe process(es) and their command line(s) as they appear in the Details list
feel free to blur any sensitive info there.

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT Thanks for your reply, I've updated the image you need in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Use advance system care https://www.iobit.com/en/advancedsystemcarefree.php
scan pc using asc
go to startup and remove edge instances
click fix issue
see screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Afvc6.png)