# I am using Microsoft Edge Chromium with Selenium and I keep on getting the msedge.exe as a startup item

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, microsoft-edge

This is the code I used for using Selenium with Microsoft Edge Chromium browser:

```
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.edge.webdriver import WebDriver

driveroptions = Options()
driveroptions.use_chromium = True
driveroptions.add_argument('--start-maximized')
driveroptions.binary_location = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"
service = Service(executable_path="msedgedriver.exe")

driver = webdriver.Edge(options=driveroptions, service=service)
```

And whenever I restart the system, I get more than 100 msedge.exe in the startup under Task Manager and get 100s of popups of msedge.exe command prompt like this [Popups picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5he9O.png). I deleted them from the startup with Autoruns but I got them again after restart. Has anyone else encountered this issue?

Comment: This is an existing issue many people are facing the same. You can check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63714703/msedge-exe-is-opening-many-command-console-with-error-createfile-settings-access)

Comment: Can you please inform us the version of the Selenium web driver, version of the Selenium, version of the Edge browser and version of the OS build? It can help us to test the issue and it can help to narrow down the issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Edge version: Version 85.0.564.44 (Official build) (64-bit)
Windows OS build: Version 1903 (OS Build 18362.1016)
Selenium version: 4.0.0a5
Selenium Edge chromium web driver version: 84.0.524.0

I had the same issue when the Edge version was 84.0 too.

Comment: Thanks for providing the environment related information. I suggest you refer the steps mentioned in [this link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/articles/known-issue-microsoft-edge-launching-on-startup/m-p/1457853) and try to provide the feedback to Microsoft using the Edge browser. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Can you pls
1. Leave the Edge command windows opened
2. Open Task Manager
3. Switch to the Details tab
4. Right click on the “Name” column header
5. Click “Select columns”
6. Check “Command line” to include the command line in the details list
7. Post a screenshot of the msedge.exe process(es) and their command line(s) as they appear in the Details list
feel free to blur any sensitive info there.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue - disabling Microsoft Edge instances in "Startup Apps" helped but new instances got created every time the program runs...

Solved by using msedge-selenium-tools as recommended by MSDN (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium?tabs=python)

Issue hasn't cropped up in several days.

Example code:

```
from msedge.selenium_tools import Edge, EdgeOptions

driverOptions = EdgeOptions()
driverOptions.use_chromium = True
driverOptions.binary_location = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"
driverOptions.add_argument("--headless")
driverOptions.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
driver = Edge(options=driverOptions)

#... use your driver

driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

---

EDIT:

Did some more testing and it looks like it is just the "driverOptions.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])" that fixes this issue. (NOT using msedge.selenium_tools).