# too many Edge instances open automatically, with “ERROR:file_io_win.cc(180)] CreateFile settings.dat: Access is denied. (0x5)”

Tags: selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

a few days ago I tested Selenium Webdriver and I encountered a problem that too many Edge instances started automatically after I turn on my computer.

I know that many people suffer from this problem, and I tried several ways to solve this, but I didn't make it.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

I already disabled the Edge instances in Startup tab. However, I want to know the radical solution to this problem.

The information is below ->

- OS: Windows 10 Ver 20H2(OS build 19042.630)
- Selenium WebDriver: 3.141.0
- Visual Studio Code: V 1.51.1(User Setup)
- Edge Browser: V 86.0.622.69 (Official build) (64-bit)

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: If possible, then I suggest you make a test with this code.  `driverOptions.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])` You can let us know about your test results. It may help you to fix this issue. [Ref. answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64146083/10309381)

Comment: It works, Thanks for your help!

Comment: from your last comment it looks like your issue is solved by the suggestion I provided in the comment. I have posted the suggestion as an answer. I suggest kindly accept the answer. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible, then I suggest you make a test with this code.

```
driverOptions.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
```

You can let us know about your test results.

It may help you to fix this issue.

Reference: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63800954/i-am-using-microsoft-edge-chromium-with-selenium-and-i-keep-on-getting-the-msedg/64146083#64146083)